# How to remove noise characters from exporting elements of list in different files using R

Tags: r, parsing, export

I am having difficulties exporting elements of a list that I created after parsing some text files in R.

This is my original file
https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZDUm3ZjzHjKnBTdF8Bw4osq4eIFXDz0JF7

then what I do is parse it, keep everything that is included in `<BODY> </BODY>`,
clear it from noise (symbols, lower case etc) and put it in a list (my original file is consisted of different texts, and I need to split them).

Then I export list's elements in different text files, but I get my text along with some useless characters that cannot be seen in R console.

Here is my code

```
library(stats)
library(dplyr)
library(proxy)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(proto) ## needed for next library
library(gsubfn) #read multiple times <BODY>
setwd("input_data")

# parse my input file
doc <- lapply( list.files(), readLines )

# parse files and keep text needed
docNew <- strapply(doc, "<BODY>(.*?)</BODY>", simplify = c)


# clear files
doc1 <- lapply(docNew, function(x) {
  text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x) %>% tolower()
  text <- gsub("\\s+", " ", text) %>% str_trim()
  return(text)
  })

for (i in 1:5) {
  write.csv( doc1[[i]], file = paste0("output/",i, ".txt"))
}
```

Now here is the thing, when I call `doc1[[1]]]` in console I get

```
>     [1] "showers continue throughout the week in the bahia cocoa zone alleviating the rought since early january an improving prospects for
> the coming temporao although normal humiity levels have not been
> restore comissaria smith sai in its weekly review the ry perio means
> the temporao will be late this year arrivals for the week ene february
> 22 were 155221 bags of 60 kilos making a cumulative total for the
> season of 593 mln against 581 at the same stage last year again it
> seems that cocoa elivere earlier on consignment was inclue in the
> arrivals figures comissaria smith sai there is still some oubt as to
> how much ol crop cocoa is still available as harvesting has
> practically come to an en with total bahia crop estimates aroun 64 mln
> bags an sales staning at almost 62 mln there are a few hunre thousan
> bags still in the hans of farmers milemen exporters an processors
> there are oubts as to how much of this cocoa woul be fit for export as
> shippers are now experiencing ificulties in obtaining ... <truncated>
```

and when I open my 1.txt file created, I have a text that looks like:

> "","x" "1","showers continue throughout the week in the bahia cocoa
>   zone alleviating the rought since early january an improving prospects
>   for the coming temporao although normal humiity levels have not been
>   restore comissaria smith sai in its weekly review the ry perio means
>   the temporao will be late this year arrivals for the week ene february
>   22 were 155221 bags of 60 kilos making a cumulative total for the
>   season of 593 mln against 581 at the same stage last year again it
>   seems that cocoa elivere earlier on consignment was inclue in the
>   arrivals figures comissaria smith sai there is still some oubt as to
>   how much ol crop cocoa is still available as harvesting has
>   practically come to an en with total bahia crop estimates aroun 64 mln
>   bags an sales staning at almost 62 mln there are a few hunre thousan
>   bags still in the hans of farmers milemen exporters an processors
>   there are oubts as to how much of this cocoa woul be fit for export as
>   shippers are now experiencing ificulties in obtaining bahia superior
>   certificates in view of the lower quality over recent weeks farmers
>   have sol a goo part of their cocoa hel on consignment comissaria smith
>   sai spot bean prices rose to 340 to 350 cruzaos per arroba of 15 kilos
>   bean shippers were reluctant to offer nearby shipment an only limite
>   sales were booke for march shipment at 1750 to 1780 lrs per tonne to
>   ports to be name new crop sales were also light an all to open ports
>   with junejuly going at 1850 an 1880 lrs an at 35 an 45 lrs uner new
>   york july augsept at 1870 1875 an 1880 lrs per tonne fob routine sales
>   of butter were mae marchapril sol at 4340 4345 an 4350 lrs aprilmay
>   butter went at 227 times new york may junejuly at 4400 an 4415 lrs
>   augsept at 4351 to 4450 lrs an at 227 an 228 times new york sept an
>   octec at 4480 lrs an 227 times new york ec comissaria smith sai
>   estinations were the us covertible currency areas uruguay an open
>   ports cake sales were registere at 785 to 995 lrs for marchapril 785
>   lrs for may 753 lrs for aug an 039 times new york ec for octec buyers
>   were the us argentina uruguay an convertible currency areas liquor
>   sales were limite with marchapril selling at 2325 an 2380 lrs junejuly
>   at 2375 lrs an at 125 times new york july augsept at 2400 lrs an at
>   125 times new york sept an octec at 125 times new york ec comissaria
>   smith sai total bahia sales are currently estimate at 613 mln bags
>   against the 198687 crop an 106 mln bags against the 198788 crop final
>   figures for the perio to february 28 are expecte to be publishe by the
>   brazilian cocoa trae commission after carnival which ens miay on
>   february 27 reuter 3"

How can I get just plain text, removing "","x" "1", and the "" around text?

I just need something like:

> showers continue throughout the week in the bahia cocoa zone
>   alleviating the rought...

I tried

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  write.csv( cat(doc1[[i]]), file = paste0("output/",i, ".txt"))
}
```

but prints only

> ""

in my exported files (it seems to work though in R console)

Comment: If you want to write to a file using `cat`, you can use `cat(doc1[[i]], file = "...")`, but not in conjunction with `write.csv`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik so basically `for (i in 1:5) {
  cat(doc1[[i]], file = paste0("output/",i, ".txt"))
}` It works, you should post it as an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a string to a file, your best bet is `cat`. It does not need any other function to work. While you could use `capture.output` or `sink` to write some convoluted stuff, the following appears to be sufficient for what you're after.

```
for (i in 1:length(doc1)) {
  cat(doc1[[i]], file = sprintf("output/file_%s.txt", i))
}
```